# I am trying to figure out whats wrong with my list

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview

The only way I can describe whats happening is with an image so I hope this shows up, I think my problem is within the itemsource because I put these in a listbox and there is no blank spaces in the email list, in col1 it shows the names, and in col2 it shows the emails, but there not on the same rows, everything is pushed down.

here is the xaml

```
    <Window x:Class="test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="492" Width="865" ResizeMode="CanMinimize">
<Grid>
    <Label Content="Name" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsEnabled="False" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,46,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180" />
    <Label Content="Email" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,138,0,0" Name="label3" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsEnabled="False" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,172,0,0" Name="textBox3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180" />
    <Label Content="Website" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,75,0,0" Name="label4" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsEnabled="False" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,109,0,0" Name="textBox4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180" />
    <Calendar Height="170" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,235,0,0" Name="calendar1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180" />
    <Label Content="Send Date" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,203,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsEnabled="False" />
    <TabControl Height="391" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="225,14,0,0" Name="tabControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="606">
        <TabItem Header="My" Name="tabItem1" IsEnabled="True">
            <Grid>
                <ListView Height="359" ItemsSource="{Binding Tab1Collection}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="listView1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="596">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding name1}" Header="Name" Width="150" />
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding email1}" Header="Email" Width="255" />
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding website1}" Header="Website" Width="200" />
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Finished" Name="tabItem2" IsEnabled="true">
            <Grid>
                <ListView Height="359" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="listView2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="596">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="150" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Email" Width="150" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Website" Width="150" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Delivered On" Width="150" />
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Results" Name="tabItem3" IsEnabled="False">
            <Grid />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Directory" Name="tabItem4" IsEnabled="true" IsSelected="True">
            <Grid Height="362"></Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
    <Button Content="Add Contact" Height="29" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="97,411,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="95" />
</Grid>
```

here is the code

```
    private List<string> names = new List<string>();
    private List<string> Emails = new List<string>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        names.Add("test123");
        names.Add("test123");
        names.Add("test123");
        names.Add("tst123");
        names.Add("test123");
        names.Add("tst123");

        Emails.Add("test123@Gmail.com");
        Emails.Add("test123@Gmail.com");
        Emails.Add("test123@Gmail.com");
        Emails.Add("test123@Gmail.com");
        Emails.Add("test123@Gmail.com");
        Emails.Add("test123@Gmail.com");

        foreach(var n in names) {
            listView1.Items.Add(new {name1 = n});
        }

        foreach(var e in Emails) {
            listView1.Items.Add(new {email1 = e});
        }








    }
```

here is the image to explain whats happening, everything should be on the same row.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Uknl.png]

Comment: Consider removing some of the bumf from your xaml to make it easier to read.

Comment: I see designer created XAML...

Answer (score 1):

You're managing two different `List`, and you're not merging them, you're inserting one list, and then another one.

Considering two `List` have the same number of `Items`, you can do something Like

```
for(int index = 0; index < names.Count;index++)
{
     listView1.Items.Add(new {email1 = Emails[index], name1 = names[index] });
}
```

I don't remember the `List` syntax and properties, so if this doesn't work (or are better options) please edit me

Comment: @Eivieejo works perfect I actually had a for loop before but i didn't merge the to list together like that, will that work for all the other colomns as well?

Comment: if you use the for for all list, and add every item you want to merge in the new inside the add, it will work

Answer (score 1):

You are adding 2 different collections to the listView by iterating through each of them separately so it's obvious that you'll get the effect you are seeing.

You need to create a class with 2 properties, `name` and `email` and then bind the `ListView` to this class. Something like:

```
public class Person
{
     public Person(string name,string email)
     { 
         Name=name;
         Email=email;
     }
     public string Name {get;set;}
     public string Email {get;set;}
}


List<Person> people = {new Person("name1","test1@gmail.com"
                      ,new Person("name2","test2@gmail.com"
                      ,new Person("name3","test3@gmail.com"
                      ,new Person("name4","test4@gmail.com")};
```

Now you can simply bind the listview as so:

```
listView1.ItemsSource=people;
```